# How Can I split A String from the end to some character I want

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-3.0

How can I split a string from the end to some character I want.
Let me explain in example

> "C:\Users\Esat\Desktop\BilimResimler\1620855_759701257391419_1132489417_n.jpg"

and I want to cut this part **1620855_759701257391419_1132489417_n.jpg** but I have a lot of image and image names always changing so i can not use substring metod.So how can i do this ?

Comment: That will depend on what you're trying to do. Are you trying to remove 1620855.... from the string leaving you with the rest of it or simply remove the rest of the filepath string and leave 1620855...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just to add to the answers - if this refers to a file that physically exists on disk, then why not let fileinfo do the work for you?

```
    var path = @"C:\Users\Esat\Desktop\BilimResimler\1620855_759701257391419_1132489417_n.jpg";

System.IO.FileInfo myImageFile = new System.IO.FileInfo(path);

Console.WriteLine(myImageFile.Name); // gives 1620855_759701257391419_1132489417_n.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

You can search for the last "\" character and eliminate everything from it, including him.

OR

From 0 to the index of the length of "C:\Users\Esat\Desktop\BilimResimler\" - 1 (37 - 1 if I counted correctly) keep the string and eliminate everything else.

Comment: Thanks for your answer secend one is very easy and simple.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
string imageNameAndPath=@"C:\Users\Esat\Desktop\BilimResimler\1620855_759701257391419_1132489417_n.jpg"
    imageNameAndPath=imageNameAndPath.Substring(0, imageNameAndPath.LastIndexOf('/'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string FileName = Path.GetFileName(Path)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get your file name using below code.

```
var path = @"C:\Users\Esat\Desktop\BilimResimler\1620855_759701257391419_1132489417_n.jpg";
        string ImgPath = path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1);
```